# Relation of bounded wildcard and function argument

Tags: java, generics, type-safety

Suppose we have `Sub` inherit `compareTo` from `Super`:

```
class Super implements Comparable<Super> {
    @Override public int compareTo(Super o) {
        return 0;
    }
}

class Sub extends Super {}
```

And generic method `max` that takes a list of `Comparable`:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T max(List<T> list) {
    return null;
}
```

If we try to call `max` with the list of `Sub`'s we will get a compile-time error because `Sub` doesn't implement `Comparable<Sub>`. This is what I expected!

```
max(new ArrayList<Sub>()); // error, Sub should implement Comparable<Sub>
```

Then I change `max` arguments to accept just two instances of T and test it:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T max(T t, T t2) {
    return null;
} 
max(new Sub(), new Sub());
```

No compile-time error, non runtime!

What is the difference between `max` methods in terms of type safety?

Comment: It's because a `Sub` is a `Super`, but a `Comparable<Sub>` is not a `Comparable<Super>` and a `List<Sub>` is not a `List<Super>`. http://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265/3973077

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`max(T,T)` lets the compiler infer that `T` can be `Super` and do a widening conversion on the arguments.

On the other hand, `max(List<T>)` is not so flexible, because generics are invariant (explained in Paul's link). The compiler can't perform a conversion on the `List`, so `T` has to be exactly `Sub`.

In both cases, you should change the type variable bound to this:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T max(List<T> list) {...}
//                                  ^^^^^^^^^
```

It's less restrictive and will let you do e.g.:

```
Sub s0 = max(new ArrayList<Sub>());
Sub s1 = max(new Sub(), new Sub());
```

Line 2 also wouldn't compile with the more restrictive bound, which you may have missed because you ignore the return value in your example.

(The `? super T` is also [how Java SE does it](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-).)